# Why hide() is behaving differently?

Tags: jquery

I want to remove the element by clicking on them(one by one). I almost done, but am experiencing a little problem.

I write this code, this work fine. But this works only for `slide()` and `css()`. These two example make effect only to the element on which I click.

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    var k = $("<p></p>").text("paragraph");
    $("#content").append(k);
});

$("#content").on("click","*",function(){
    $(this).slideToggle();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k61Lb684/

https://jsfiddle.net/k61Lb684/1/

But the problem is I want to remove the element But when I try to `remove()` or `hide()`  with same method, it only hides the bottom element.

https://jsfiddle.net/k61Lb684/2/

https://jsfiddle.net/k61Lb684/3/

Can someone Explain why this different behaviour for `hide()` and `remove()`. and a better solution for my problem?

Comment: It seems that's the last one is removed but that's not the case. Here an example: https://jsfiddle.net/jkbqso0L/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hide` and `remove` workes the same way. But both don't have a `animation` time by default. So both are so fast, that it visible seems, that the last row would be removed. But the truth is, that the bottom elements slide up to the new empty space in the list.

You can see the correct behavior when giving `hide` a time for it's animation:

```
$(this).hide(500);
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/k61Lb684/5/)**

Comment: Read my answer again, I descriped the behavior. It only visible seems to removes the last line, but it doesn't. @user6733315